# G++ Error Message "Operands to ?: have different types" but I Have Two Times the Same Type

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

Why does the code below not compile? g++ outputs the error message:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘void test(bool)’:
test.cpp:11:15: error: operands to ?: have different types ‘test(bool)::<lambda(int)>’ and ‘test(bool)::<lambda(int)>’
     yadda(flag?x:y);
           ~~~~^~~~
```

Which makes little sense to me, as the two types given in the error message seem to be the same. I am using the following code:

```
#include <functional>

void yadda(std::function<int(int)> zeptok) {
    zeptok(123);
}

void test(bool flag) {
    int a = 33;
    auto x = [&a](int size){ return size*3; };
    auto y = [&a](int size){ return size*2; };
    yadda(flag?x:y);
}
```

I compile with "g++ -c test.cpp -std=c++14" and my GCC version is "6.3.0 20170406 (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2)".

Comment: Individual lambdas have their own individual implementations, and as such they are treated as individual types, even if they happen to have the same signature.

Comment: ....sounds very reasonable, but shouldn't the error message reflect this? Currently it says, for some "A" that A is not the same as A.

Answer (score 5):

The message is correct. Each lambda is a different type. Think of them as two different structs that both define `operator()`. Use a `std::function` instead of `auto`:

```
void test(bool flag) {
    int a = 33;
    std::function<int (int)> x = [&a](int size){ return size*3; };
    std::function<int (int)> y = [&a](int size){ return size*2; };
    yadda(flag?x:y);
}
```

Comment: ....sounds very reasonable, but shouldn't the error message reflect this? Currently it says, for some "A" that A is not the same as A

Comment: @DCTLib yes, if you don't know the problem the message isn't very helpful. What version of g++ do you use? IIRC I have seen g++ messages about lambdas with some cryptical names for each lambda.

Comment: I use "G++ 6.3.0 20170406" - The current one for Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: It is unlikely to get a readable name for lambdas IMO, they are, after all, anonymous.